# TradingView Pivot Reversal Strategy

Tags: pivot, bitcoin, pine-script, technical-indicator

The Pivot Reversal Strategy in TradingView includes in the script the function "pivothigh" and "pivotlow".

The exact mathematical formula is not available in the Pine Documentation. Could you provide the exact mathematical definition of the the pivots? It doesnt seem be just swing highs/lows (i.e. middle of range candlestick bar has highest or lowest low...)

I need it to better understand the strategy and potentially re-coding with some adjustments.

Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score -1):

The function `pivothigh(source, leftbars, rightbars)` returns a pivot (the value of `source` at the pivot point, so `source[rightbars]`) if the `leftbars` and `rightbars` values of `source` are less than or equal to the value of `source` at the pivot. It returns `na` otherwise.

> Note that when a pivot is found, its value will only be returned `rightbars` after the pivot.